# couldn't find the image variable which help me to upload to wordpress theme php api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, postman

So i am making a classified website with wordpress and classima theme, i am testing out upload the image with the help of postman.
Below is the theme code responsible for api upload to the website and i couldn't figure out which variable to use in my postman body to upload to website using api.
I am able to set new listing title, price and everything but for image i can not figure out how to do it. Please see my attached screenshot of postman for what i have tried

```
$files = $request->get_file_params();
        $uploaded_images = [];
        if (!empty($files['gallery']['name'])) {
            $gallery = $files['gallery'];
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            foreach ($gallery['name'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($gallery['name'][$key]) {
                    $image = array(
                        'name'     => $gallery['name'][$key],
                        'type'     => $gallery['type'][$key],
                        'tmp_name' => $gallery['tmp_name'][$key],
                        'error'    => $gallery['error'][$key],
                        'size'     => $gallery['size'][$key]
                    );

                    Filters::beforeUpload();
                    $status = wp_handle_upload($image, ['test_form' => false]);
                    Filters::afterUpload();
                    if ($status && !isset($status['error'])) {
                        $filename = $status['file'];
                        $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename));
                        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                        $attachment = [
                            'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename),
                            'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                            'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                            'post_content'   => '',
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                        ];
                        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $listing_id);
                        if (!is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
                            $uploaded_images[$image['name']] = $attach_id;
                            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $listing = rtcl()->factory->get_listing($listing_id);
```

[image: postman body screenshot]